# fatal error: IPvXAddress.h: No such file or directory

Tags: omnet++, inet

During compilation of project in Omnetpp I encountered the following error:

> applications/denacastapp/TransportAddress.h:33:10: fatal error: IPvXAddress.h: No such file or directory
> #include "IPvXAddress.h"
> compilation terminated.
>
> Makefile:245: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/applications/denacastapp/DenaCastApp.o' failed
> make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/applications/denacastapp/DenaCastApp.o] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shivanshu/Documents/FinalProject/Software/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/Kunwar/src'
> Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2

On internet I found about reinstallation of inet as solution but I couldn't resolve the issue.
Please help !!

Comment: Have you created a new project or added a code to existing code of INET?

Comment: I have created a new project.During build it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you set INET as a reference project for your project?